# Is a process moved to other NUMA nodes by linux kernel implicitly?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling, numa

I am wondering if a process is moved to other NUMA nodes by linux kernel implicitly for the purpose of load balancing.

If it does, could you tell me when it happens?

Thank you.